# Java Programming using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

where does the java file, for example: Employee1.java goes after it is saved in eclipse?

Comment: interesting, a specific class for employee number 1.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click on the file in Package Explorer
2. Properties
3. Resource
4. `Path` - a relative path to the file (based on project's root), `Location` - an absolute path to the file in filesystem

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have made your java code by selecting new in your java resource:src under your project....
if so then it will go in the projectname/src folder in your workspace.............
once you write it eclipse automatically compiles it and stores it in the bin folder of ur workspace from where it uses it.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out the path of your workspace go to File->Switch Workspace->Other... then in the popup dialog, the shown path is your workspace path.

Now use file explorer to explore the workspace path and see if the folders under it looks familiar to you 
:-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your **work space**( you are given while eclipse startup)
2. After open the work space select your **project**.
3. Inside of the project, open **src** folder.
4. Your **Employee1.java** file stored in inside this **src** folder.

simple way,

```
work space --> select your project --> open **src** folder --> open Employee1.java file.
```

Or

```
right click the project --> go to properties --> see the path on resource.
```